# How to do broadcast in Pulsar

Tags: apache-pulsar, pulsar

I'm investigating a tech for our cluster. Pulsar looks good, but the usage looks more like a queueing system. Of course, queueing system is good to have, but I have a specific requirement: broadcasting.

We would like to use one machine to generate the data and publish it to a Pulsar topic. Then we use a group of servers, forming a replica. Each server consumes the message flow on that topic, and serves clients via WebSocket.

This is different than the Shared subscription, because each server needs to receive *all* messages, not a fraction of it.

I came to this post: https://kafkaesque.io/subscriptions-multiple-groups-of-consumers-on-pulsar-topic/ , which explains how to do such a job: each server needs create a new exclusive subscription, say use a UUID as its subscription name, from the unique exclusive subscription you can get the full message flow of that topic.

But since our server replica can be dynamic, so once some of the server restart, they will create new UUID subscription again, which will leave many orphan subscriptions on the topic, which eventually would become maintenance headache.

Anyone has the experience to setup a broadcast use case using Pulsar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an exclusive subscription for each consumer is the only way to ensure that each of your consumers receives ALL of the messages on the topic, and Pulsar handles multiple subscriptions quite well.

The issue it seems is the server restart use case, and I don't think that simply connecting with a new UUID subscription is the right approach (putting aside the orphaned subscriptions). You really want to have the server reuse the previous subscription after it restarts. This is because each subscription keeps track of the last message in the topic that it had processed and acknowledged, so you can pick up exactly where you had left off before the server crashed if you reconnect with the same subscription UUID. If you connect with a new UUID, then you will start processing messages produced from that point in time forward, and all messages produced during the restart period will be "lost"

Therefore, you will need to find a mechanism to share these UUIDs across server failures and return them to the restarting server. One approach would be to have a mechanism similar to zookeeper leader election, in which each server is granted an exclusive lease that expires periodically. The server must then periodically refresh the lease to retain it. Then if the server were to crash, it would fail to refresh the lease on that UUID and the restarting server would then be granted the lease when it attempts to reconnect.

See https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/leader-election.html for a better explanation of the pattern.

Comment: thanks very much. I agree with you about the advantages to try to re-use a subscription. But in my case, actually it is not so important to get the messages that generated during the crash time. It is more like a metrics reporter, and I just want to have a dynamic robust way (using Kubernetes Deployment) to serve more WebSocket clients. So any suggestions on this use case? I found it is not so easy to delete unused subscriptions. Or maybe a cleanup job that tries to subscribe all subscriptions, and delete those without exceptions (if it is occupied, it will throw exception because of exclusive

Comment: to be more specific, my use case is more like a metrics reporter, and my nodes are stateless, they can started any time, and process the messages that generated really at NOW, it just start, and work with messages from now on.

Comment: Assuming you can quickly identify the unused subscriptions, there is a REST API call that should do the trick. https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/pulsar-admin/#unsubscribe-1

Comment: I think I can create a kubernetes cronjob, and use the API not the CLI to do the job, it just grab all subscriptions of a topic, and try to subscribe each of them, and if they are successfully subscribed (no exclusive exception), then I can use API to delete it (I am new to Pulsar, but I guess there must be some subscription management API out there)

Comment: Ah, you mean REST, that is kind of API

Comment: Yes, the CLI commands are are backed by equivalent REST API calls.

Comment: You can also delete a subscription using Java,  if that is easier for you. https://pulsar.apache.org/api/admin/2.5.0-SNAPSHOT/org/apache/pulsar/client/admin/Topics.html#deleteSubscription-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: Yes, thanks, I use Scala Pulsar library, which is wrapper over Java client.

Comment: Actually, I found that the new "Reader Interface" is exactly for this use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60711436/whats-the-difference-between-backlog-quotas-and-ttl

Comment: @XiangZhang Following this thread, the requirement seems like your applications do not prefer to have any state. The state means to track the subscription name. With a topic compaction workaround to use a reader interface, the data integrity can be eroded. As long as you can store the state somewhere, it can be retrieved for subscription name. A state can be the name of k8s stateful set or simply use another pulsar topic to store the subscription name. IMHO, you are making trade off between minimum cost of state management and data integrity.

Comment: @MingL. yes, I used Reader interface, it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I found that the "Reader Interface" is exactly for this kind of use case:

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-clients/#reader-interface

Comment: So your plan is to have a separate reader for each server replica? How will you coordinate the message index between the "failed" servers and their replacement when it comes back online?

Comment: In the topic message stream, I periodically insert some snapshot (or "image") of the full picture, so if a new server started, it can wait a little bit of the time, then it can get the snapshot, then it start to serve from then on. The "Reader interface" does exactly what you said under the hood, it create a "temp" subscription and will delete once reader died, I tested that, works perfect, you can see the temp subscription in the Pulsar dashboard.

Comment: It's kind like a compaction